# Postfix: permission denied error while the incoming mail reading from python script

Tags: python, linux, permissions, postfix-mta

I want to get a copy of incoming mail from Postfix to my python script.I did postfix configuration exactly like this https://serverfault.com/questions/536648/postfix-pass-a-copy-of-an-email-to-a-script-but-deliver-the-original-one-to-mai and the postfix send a copy of email to script.But the problem that while python script execution there is a Permission denied error. It is from /var/log/mail.log :

```
    Apr 29 12:56:26 mail postfix/smtpd[7740]: connect from mail-wr1-x429.google.com[2a00:1450:4864:20::429]
Apr 29 12:56:26 mail postfix/smtpd[7740]: 84F503FE97: client=mail-wr1-x429.google.com[2a00:1450:4864:20::429]
Apr 29 12:56:26 mail postfix/cleanup[7747]: 84F503FE97: message-id=<CAHDgzXAk54JCjKKVesC2YR+oiD48uT0dE191znr_wd+t1jCp7A@mail.gmail.com>
Apr 29 12:56:26 mail postfix/qmgr[1231]: 84F503FE97: from=<example@gmail.com>, size=2513, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Apr 29 12:56:26 mail postfix/smtpd[7740]: disconnect from mail-wr1-x429.google.com[2a00:1450:4864:20::429] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
Apr 29 12:56:26 mail postfix/local[7749]: 84F503FE97: to=<exampleUser@mydomain.xyz>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Apr 29 12:56:26 mail postfix/local[7750]: 84F503FE97: to=<pythonscript@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.08, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced 
(Command died with status 1: "/usr/bin/python /home/pythonscript/pythonscript.py". Command output: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pythonscript/pythonscript.py", line 1, in <module>     f = open("file.txt", "w") IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'file.txt' )
Apr 29 12:56:26 mail postfix/qmgr[1231]: 84F503FE97: removed
Apr 29 12:56:26 mail postfix/cleanup[7747]: 9693A41B8D: message-id=<20200429125626.9693A41B8D@mail.example.xyz>
```

and my python script is like :

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write("Woops! I have deleted the content!")
f.close()
```

This is the error from /var/mail/mail.log

```
Apr 29 12:56:26 mail postfix/local[7750]: 84F503FE97: to=<pythonscript@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.08, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced 
(Command died with status 1: "/usr/bin/python /home/pythonscript/pythonscript.py". Command output: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pythonscript/pythonscript.py", line 1, in <module>     f = open("file.txt", "w") IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'file.txt' )
```

I tried to change some user permission but ı did not solve the problem.

Thanks a lot for your answers!!

Answer (score 0):

Okey guts ı solved it !  Firstly postfix uses the nobody user to pipe process adn nobody user not a privilaged user.

Create system user for example "user1"

```
adduser user1
```

Then add /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
default_privs = user1
```

Give sudo permission to user1

```
usermod -aG sudo user1
```

Then change script directory permission

```
chmod 777 /full/path/to/script/directory
```

chmod 777 can be some security problem. you can give permission to directory which more suitable.